# Order an array of objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two `NSManagedObject` created in my project called `Contact` and `Groups`. Both object have a property named `timeLastMessageReceived`.
I have a array containing both objects.

I want order that array by time of `timeLastMessageReceived`.

```
@interface Contact : NSManagedObject

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeLastMessageReceived;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastMessage;

@end



@interface Groups : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeLastMessageReceived;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastMessage;

@end
```

I'm trying this method :

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSArray *newArr = [self.chatArray sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *date1 = obj1[@"timeLastMessageReceived"];
        NSDate *date2 = obj2[@"timeLastMessageReceived"];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
```

but it's crashing with error: -`[Contact objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

As an alternative you could sort the array using sort descriptors:

```
NSSortDescriptor *timeLastMessageReceivedDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeLastMessageReceived" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[timeLastMessageReceivedDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.chatArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

**Original answer:**

I guess `self.chatArray` contains instances of type `Contact`? You should be able to implement the comparator like that then:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSArray *newArr = [self.chatArray sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Contact *contact1, Contact *contact2) {
    NSDate *date1 = contact1.timeLastMessageReceived;
    NSDate *date2 = contact2.timeLastMessageReceived;
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: No, containt instance of type Contact and Groups

Comment: OK, but that not a real problem here thanks to Objective-C's dynamic runtime. Since both types implement a property named `timeLastMessageReceived` everything should be fine. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33260955/3617012 explains how it should be done correctly though.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative approach to sort the array (without the need to rewrite the rest of the code like adding a protocol).

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `[]` operator (i.e. `-objectForKeyedSubscript:`) on instances of `NSDictionary`. As the error message states, you are dealing with an instance of `Contact`, and as such it does not support the subscript operator.

You show how `timeLastMessageReceived` is simply a property on `Contact`, so you should just be able to use the default property access syntax:

```
    NSDate *date1 = obj1.timeLastMessageReceived;
    NSDate *date2 = obj2.timeLastMessageReceived;
```

Comment: i'm getting an error when i'm trying this: Property 'timeLastMessgaeReceived' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. See @Marcos Crispino's answer for how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a protocol implemented by both Contact and Group, that defines the `timeLastMessageReceived` property.

```
@protocol ContactOrGroupProtocol
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeLastMessageReceived;
@end
```

Then, the comparator block would be:

```
^NSComparisonResult(id<ContactOrGroupProtocol> obj1, id<ContactOrGroupProtocol> obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = obj1.timeLastMessageReceived;
    NSDate *date2 = obj2.timeLastMessageReceived;
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: Where i need to create this protocol?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to implement the comparison method in the class `Groups` and `Contact`

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareLastMessageReceived:(Groups *)group {
  return [self.timeLastMessageReceived compare:group.timeLastMessageReceived];
}

- (NSComparisonResult)compareLastMessageReceived:(Contact *)contact {
  return [self.timeLastMessageReceived compare:contact.timeLastMessageReceived];
}
```

and call `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`

```
NSArray *newArr = [self.chatArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareLastMessageReceived:)];
```